# show that if $x$ is not free in $\Psi$ then $\phi \rightarrow\Psi\vDash [(\exists x \phi)\rightarrow\Psi]$

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

show that if $x$ is not free in $\Psi$  then

$$\phi \rightarrow\Psi\vDash [(\exists x \phi)\rightarrow\Psi]$$
answer: by QR $$\phi \rightarrow\Psi\vdash [(\exists x \phi)\rightarrow\Psi]$$
so theorem soundness $\Rightarrow$$$\phi \rightarrow\Psi\vDash [(\exists x \phi)\rightarrow\Psi]$$
could i tell this way?

Comment: Yes, it is correct : see Ch.Leary, page 61 for the quantifier rule. The proviso : $x$ not free in $\Psi$ is necessary.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What can go wrong when $x$ is not free in $\Psi$?

Comment: @Trismegistos - Consider the *valid* formula : $x=0 \rightarrow x=0$. Applying the rule without taking care of the proviso we would have : $\exists x(x=0) \rightarrow x=0$. We want that consequences of valid formulae are valid also, but the last one is **not** valid.